# Use format string to smash the stack

Tags: c, security

Well I am trying to smash the stack using a special format string,

```
void func(char *param){
   char buf[200]; // &buffer = 0xffbfdc10
   snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"Test:%s is this going to work?\n",param);
   printf(buf);
}

int main(void){
   char buf[400];
   strcpy(buffer,"%199d\x10\xdc\xbf\xff");
   strcat(buffer,shellcode); // shellcode is fairly short(less than 100 byte)
   func(buf);
   exit(0);
}
```

The "%199d" is because 200 - strlen("Test:")+4 = 199, which indicates where RET pointer may live.

So by my design, when executing printf(buf), firstly there are 199 decimals pushed into buf[] right after "Test:" literal, and then the RET pointer will be overwritten with value = 0xffbfdc10. Then the program will jump back to where shellcode lives.

However, it is completely not what I was imagining. Basically overwriting RET fails, even though shellcode does live in the buf[] and addresses are all correct(by gdb, x/x addr, print &var, etc). There must be something really important I was missing in the format string.

Can someone give me a hint about correcting that format string?

Comment: If your shellcode has any zero bytes in it, then neither `strcat` nor `snprintf` will write the whole thing to `buf`. And if you want your shellcode to be in buf, then it should be written first. In your code, you're attempting to write it after `buf`. Just pass in `shellcode`, `memcpy` it to `buf`, then write `buf`'s address at `buf+200`.